# Javafx HtmlEditor: preview color is so small

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

In HTMLEditor of JavaFX: the preview color is so small.

[image]

I want to show bigger like picture below:
[image]

How i can do.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style of the HTMLEditor is customized via CSS.

```
.html-editor-foreground {
    -fx-color-rect-width: 16;
    -fx-color-rect-height: 16;
    -fx-graphic: null;
}
```

Here we style the foreground color picker picked color indicator as a (relatively) large rectangle (with a pink color chosen for the sample):

[image: custom]

*Sample Code*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class EditorSample extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        HTMLEditor editor = new HTMLEditor();

        Scene scene = new Scene(editor);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(
                this.getClass().getResource(
                        "html-editor-large-color-rect.css"
                ).toExternalForm()
        );
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, jewelsea!